# How to separate columns with double quotes and comma?

Tags: bash, awk

I want space separated columns with comma separate, double quote enclose output. May be the following example will clear what I actually want.

I have the following

```
abc def fgi > klj 2> pqr
```

I want to have

```
"abc", "def", "fgi", ">", "klj", "2>", "pqr"
```

btw, the length may vary. There are more than 100s line with different column number.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: you can use the sed only solution since you need to operate on a file instead of single variable, and change single quotes to double quotes

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes I tried ofcourse. Replacing space to double quotes can be done easily. I am confused on how to enclose with doublequote for first column and neglect comma in last column

@ Sundeep not really. I am not sure how to do in sed. If this can be done using sed then it's fine.

Comment: @Sundeep alright, `STR1="'${STR1// /\',\'}'"` this is what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @Err0rr `sed`only solution is the last answer in the question marked as duplicate